# Enable Wireless option is disabled in network settings in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, bluetooth

My wireless connections have regularly disconnected with the Wireless option disabled in network settings. This problem occurs frequently. After restarting, I can access. But again an error comes after some time (there is no fixed interval). Please suggest what to do. Below is the description. There is only one switch to enable/disable bluetooth and wifi.

```
$ rfkill list all
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
25: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the output of 'sudo lshw -C network' after your connection has broken. If no Wifi device is listed, you may have a hardware problem.
I had the same problem and it turned out that the Wifi adaptor was not seated properly in it's socket.